# Convert HTML Webpage to a Windows Gadget

Tags: html, windows, sidebar, windows-desktop-gadgets, liquid

I wanted to convert a webpage to a Windows Gadget. Basically, the Webpage has nothing but 2 or 3 images & a countdown. I tried to do it but unfortunately the size of the gadget shrinked to like around 2px width by 8px height. I tried Amnesty Generator but I want the gadget to work offline too.

P.S. I made the html page liquid so that the gadget wouldn't have any problem.

Regards,
Netizen

Comment: Are you sure that the liquid contents of the page are not causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set height and width of the  element in your css.

```
body
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```